# Dispersion relation in $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=c^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + ac^2\frac{d^4y}{dx^4}$

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, dispersion

So I was reading through some lectures notes and I found this:
The equation of motion of a non-ideal string is $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=c^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + ac^2\frac{d^4y}{dx^4}$ and we are asked to compute $\omega(k)$. But with no previous step, the writer says:
$\omega^2 = c^2k^2 + ac^2 k^4$.

I usually work problems as such by making an hypothesis for the general solution of the differential equation . Then I subsitute the potential solution to the equation and I derive the $\omega(k)$. In this problem are we supposed to know the general solution or is it something else that the writer knows and does it right away?

Comment: Because $y=y(x,t)$ your differentials should be partials: $\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}=...$ Its' a PDE, not an ODE.

Comment: and what about the formula for k? is it awlays true?

Comment: The problem lacks boundary conditions.

Comment: @Gert there are not provided though, somehow I feel like we don't have to compute the exact formula of $y$ but rather it's general form to derive the dispersion relation

Comment: I've elaborated somewhat, hope it helps!

Comment: @brucebanner If possible I would like to know if the lecture notes are of non-linear waves?

Answer (score 0):

The PDE:

$$\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2}=c^2\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2} + ac^2\frac{\partial^4y}{\partial x^4}$$

The Ansatz:
$$y(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$$

Separation of variables:
$$X(x)T''(t)=c^2T(t)X''(x)+ac^2T(t)X^{(4)} (x)$$
$$\frac{T''}{c^2 T}=\frac{X''}{X}+a\frac{X^{(4)}}{X}=-k^2$$
$$\frac{X''}{X}+a\frac{X^{(4)}}{X}=-k^2$$
The $x$ based ODE:

$$aX^{(4)}+X''+k^2X=0\tag{1}$$

[Which has the general solution shown here (Wolfram alpha)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ay%27%27%27%27%28x%29%2By%27%27%28x%29%2Bk%5E2%20y%28x%29%3D0).

The time based ODE:

$$\frac{T''(t)}{c^2 T(t)}=-k^2$$
$$T''(t)+c^2 k^2 T(t)=0$$
$$T(t)=A\sin(c k t)+B\cos(c k t)$$
$$\omega=ck$$
It should be possible to obtain $k$ from $(1)$ and the (not provided) boundary conditions.

Wikipedia does provide the [dipersion relation for a stiff spring as:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation#Waves_on_a_string)

$$\omega^2=\frac{T}{\mu}k^2+\alpha k^4$$